# Calling share sheet from UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Trying to wrap my head around with an issue I'm facing. I want to press a button and share a URL via share sheet. Here is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
class SideMenu: UIView {
    //share app 
    @IBAction func shareAppBtn(sender: AnyObject ) {
        print("shareAppBtn tapped")
        let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        guard let url = myWebsite else {
            print("nothing found")
            return
        }      
        let shareItems:Array = [url]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```

Which gave me the following error:  `Value of type 'SideMenu' has no member 'presentViewController'`. I think the above doesn't work because presentViewController is a component of UIViewcontroller and I'm calling it from UIView.

So instead I tried the following, attempting to call UIViewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
class SideMenu: UIView {
//share app 
@IBAction func shareAppBtn(sender: AnyObject, viewController : UIViewController) -> Void
{
    print("shareAppBtn tapped")
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }
    let shareItems:Array = [url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    viewController.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```

But the above gave me the following error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe93acb6720'`.

So I finally tried with:

```
import UIKit
class SideMenu: UIView {
//share app 
@IBAction func shareAppBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("shareAppBtn tapped")
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }
    let shareItems:Array = [url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But the above gave me the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fe03e04c600>  on <RAMAnimatedTabBarController.RAMAnimatedTabBarController: 0x7fe03bc4a170> which is already presenting <SideMenu.UISideMenuNavigationController: 0x7fe03c094200>
```

What am I missing here? I want to call a share sheet on a UIView.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't just decide to change the function signature of an `@IBAction` method.  Your problem is that this code probably doesn't belong in the `UIView`; You should either use a delegation pattern to pass the tap event out to the containing view controller, or have the containing view controller set a reference to itself in a property of your UIView so that you can know which object to call `presentViewController` on

Comment: try giving a delay before presenting `UIActivityViewcontroller`, error seems to mean this.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected.. UIViews aren't supposed to be presenting views. They should be reporting to delegates which would handle that.

In the case of `SideMenu`, your UIView, you'd need a delegate to handle what it's doing... e.g. set the view controller which presents SideMenu as the delegate..

So using a bit of example code I whipped up..

```
protocol SideMenuDelegate {

    func sideMenuDidShare()

}
```

The delegate protocol is what the view controller which handles your SideMenu view would implement.

```
class SideMenu: UIView {
    var delegate: SideMenuDelegate?
}
```

In the SideMenu view class, you'd add a delegate property.

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuDelegate {

    func sideMenuDidShare() {
        print("this is where your share code goes and where you can present other viewControllers from")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sideMenu = self.view as? SideMenu
        sideMenu?.delegate = self

    }

}
```

In the view controller which handles the SideMenu, you'd implement the SideMenuDelegate protocol e.g. `class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuDelegate`

Doing so allows your SideMenu to tell it's delegate (the ViewController) when something happens, in this case, the implemented `func sideMenuDidShare()`.

Comment: Adrian thanks for the detailed info, I think I'm understanding how delagtes work. However the code you provided doesn't seem to be working, when I click on `shareAppBtn` button the print from `SideMenuViewController` isn't being displayed? just as an FYI I ensured all `sideMenuDidShare` from your code is renamed to `shareAppBtn`.

Comment: I've written a quick example for you and uploaded to my dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61211034/Stackoverflow/DelegateFun.zip Hope it helps!

Comment: By the way, all you need to do when you run the app in the sim or on a device is tap the orange square. Thats the "UIView" which I called SideMenu for your convenience :)

Comment: Adrian I have been trying to get this to work the past two days now and unfortunately it is still not working using your suggestion. I also tried to load your app, while I can see the orange box nothing actually happens when I click on it. Nothing happens when I click my button either, no errors.

Comment: I also tried the suggestion found here https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-weak-delegates-swift/ but that didn't help my case either. I can't get button actions in the slide menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the above problem in Swift 4 - and I hope it helps.

First I created a .swift file: `SideMenuShareDelegate`, which had this protocol:

```
protocol SideMenuShareDelegate {
    func initiateShare()
}
```

Then, I implemented this protocol above in the `SideMenu` UIView class, like so:

```
    import UIKit

    class SideMenu: UIView { 

    var sideShareDelegate: SideMenuShareDelegate?

    @IBAction func shareAppBtn(_ sender: Any) {
      sideShareDelegate.initiateShare()
    }

}
```

What this is basically saying is, there's a func known as `initiateShare()` inside the `SideMenuViewController` (which you'll see below) and this will be called whenever user clicks `shareAppBtn`.

So now, inside the `SideMenuViewController`, I'll implement the protocol and add the `UIActivityViewController` functionality inside this `initiateShare()` in this manner:

```
import UIKit 

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuShareDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     SideMenuView?.sideShareDelegate = self
   }

  func initiateShare(){
   //UIActivityViewController functionality goes here

     let t = "www.my-website.com"
     let textToShare = [t]

     let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
     activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 

     self.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
  }
}
```

And this should make the activityView work perfectly! This worked for me, hope it does for you too :)